# Why wouldn't it always work to properly sum two float values?

Tags: java, types, sum

The output the following example gives me is super weird, if you ask me. How can this be possible? Is there a way to sum those two values properly? Float.sum(float a, float b) is also giving me the same results.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Sum: " + new DecimalFormat("#").format((1500036225984102400.f + 2000000000.f)));
  }
}
```

The output is:

> Sum: 1500036225984102400

Of course I would expect that those two values get summed, but it seems like the second value is just getting ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at how float is set up ([IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)), you quickly see that you only have 23 bits for the mantissa (actually 24, one is implicit for non-denormalized numbers).

1500036225984102400 is hexadecimally

```
14 d1 33 00 00 00 00 00
```

so you see, the non-null part of your number fits into these 24 bits. This is why you get the number printed exactly as you gave it. Any further bits will simply be cut off (similar to integer division, although not exactly the same in detail). Actually, this is mathematically rounding.

So if you now compare your two numbers:

```
14 d1 33 00 00 00 00 00
            77 35 94 00
```

you quickly see that the result of the addition won't fit into the available 24 bits and what does not fit, gets simply rounded away – exactly the number you tried to add...

This is generally a problem with floating point numbers, but gets visible less often with double as mantissa and exponent are simply larger there...

Answer (score 4):

Floating point numbers have a finite precision. You can find the next largest number representable using the [`Math.nextUp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-float-) method. For example, you can find the next largest number than your first operand using:

```
float next = Math.nextUp(1500036225984102400.f);
```

You can get the size of the jump between a number and its next largest number either by subtraction, or using [`Math.ulp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-float-), which tell you the size of a "unit in the last place", the amount the number increases by if you tweak the least significant bit:

```
float ulp = Math.ulp(1500036225984102400.f);
```

You'll find that this number is larger than `2000000000.f`:

```
Math.ulp(1500036225984102400.f) = 137438953472.0
                                    2000000000.0
```

Hence the sum of your two numbers cannot represented more precisely with a `float` than `1500036225984102400.f`.